# Mounting component instance to $root from plugin

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a plugin, where there will be a single instance of ModalsContainer per $root.
Because of that - I want to create the instance manually, rather than having people add `<v-modalscontainer/>` to their app.

Code below does just that, it loads components and registers them for Vue to use, then creates an instance of the container and mounts it - **the issue is, it's mounted nowhere - the method mounted() of component has console.log() in it and clearly it gets executed without an issue - but it's not mounted in any of $roots**.

```js
import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'
import ModalContainer from './components/ModalsContainer.vue'

const plugin =
{
    install(Vue, options = {})
    {
        Vue.component('v-modal', Modal)
        Vue.component('v-modalscontainer', ModalContainer)

        var instance = new (Vue.extend(ModalContainer))
        instance.$mount()
    }
}

export default plugin
```

Comment: Why not pass a selector in the second argument (`options`)?

Comment: @YomS. That's an interesting approach. It would definitely work, but I'm trying to achieve this without extra 'pointing to a direction'. Is there a way to detect all $roots?

Comment: Then perhaps create an element and append it onto the `document.body`, and mount this `Modal` instance on it. How about that?

Comment: @YomS. I somewhat gave up on the idea of automatically mounting container to $roots - I add them manually now. The problem is with re-mounting modals.

Comment: Re-mounting modals? Didn't you say the modal needs to be a singleton? Actually I played around with this and managed to get it working to where it installed without having to specify a selector nor any options. FWIW, the key is what I said in my previous comment above: appending dynamic element onto the `document.body`.

Comment: @YomS. container is the first child of $root, but modals are nested deep, inside child components - including router-view from Vue-Router.

What I want is kinda unmount() from wherever it's mounted, then remount() as child of container.

Comment: Hm, not sure why you would unmount it at all. But anyway, good luck with your other approach (mean it in a good way)!

Comment: @YomS. because otherwise this.$on doesn't work, if Modal isn't a child of ModalsContainer.

Thanks anyways.